# Package installation confusion

Tags: turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am missing something obvious, maybe you can help. I have a ROS install on my laptop that I have used with both turtlebot and turtlebot3. I am having a problem which I might have traced to diagnostic_agg. What is happening is that the msg that is published has a value at `msg.status[7].values[1].value` which I expected to see at status[7].

And given that these two robots are similar but not identical I started thinking that the fact that I have both turtlebot3 and turtlebot on the same computer may be the problem. So I double check my directories and I am not sure now whether turtlebot package is actually there. Here's what I did:

```
$ ls ~/catkin_make/src
CMakeLists.txt  cr_ros  cr_web  rosbook  turtlebot3  turtlebot3_msgs  turtlebot3_simulations

$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot
 sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-kinetic-turtlebot is already the newest version (2.4.2-0xenial-20181203-135343-0800).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-34 linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-34-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index-v4.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
Add distro "indigo"
Add distro "jade"
Add distro "kinetic"
Add distro "lunar"
Add distro "melodic"
updated cache in /home/pitosalas/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache

rospack find turtlebot
[rospack] Error: package 'turtlebot' not found
```

However:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep turtlebot
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot                        2.4.2-0xenial-20181203-135343-0800                    amd64        The turtlebot meta package provides all the basic drivers for running and using a TurtleBot.
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup                2.4.2-0xenial-20181203-130710-0800                    amd64        turtlebot_bringup provides roslaunch scripts for starting the TurtleBot base functionality.
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot-capabilities           2.4.2-0xenial-20181107-032940-0800                    amd64        Capabilities for the TurtleBot
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot-description            2.4.2-0xenial-20180825-011706-0800                    amd64        turtlebot_description provides a complete 3D model of the TurtleBot for simulation and visualization.
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot-navigation             2.3.7-0xenial-20181203-134700-0800                    amd64        turtlebot_navigation
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot-teleop                 2.4.2-0xenial-20181203-134652-0800                    amd64        Provides teleoperation using joysticks or keyboard.
```

Here's the relvant part of my .bashrc

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

#export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://roscore1.cs.brandeis.edu:11311
#export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://129.64.147.94:11311
#export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
#export TB3_MODEL=burger
# export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://`myip`:11311

source ~/mydev/rosutils/.rosbash
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://129.64.243.64:11311
export ROS_IP=`myip`
```

### Solved

But unfortunately I don't have a clear idea of how I solved it. I went through the usual 'hygiene' steps of updating packages, running make again, rebooting both the robot and the laptop, and the problem went away. But I am quite sure the problem was there as I described it, I just don't have a hypoothesis of what was going wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311319/package-installation-confusion/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-12-21**:
So what do you get when you run `env | grep ROS` and `env | grep PATH` ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-22**:
I'm confused @pitosalas: did you unmark my answer as the answer? Any particular reason?

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-12-22**:
Sorry @gvdhoorn you've been very helpful always. I had a dilemma, both the answers helped me solve the problem. I just clicked the one that was more comprehensive and which referred to yours also. In reality I am not sure how I fixed the problem.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-22**:
No need to apologise. I was just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's unlikely that having both the turtlebot and turtlebot3 packages installed on your system will cause interference.

It looks like the turtlebot is not in your workspace or on your path if rospack cannot find it. Have you sourced the kinetic `setup.bash`? Please edit your post to share what you're doing to setup your bash terminal including showing relevant parts of your .bashrc if there are ROS releated settings in there.

@gvdhoorn is right that the metapackage isn't expected to be found.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, `rospack find` doesn't work for metapackages, which `turtlebot` is (see #q137216 fi).

Try `find`ing any of the other turtlebot packages.

Also: if you've installed things using `apt`, a simple `dpkg -l | grep turtlebot` might be more informative.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2